# Deleted downloads folder

Tags: files

Hello I accidentally "deleted" my downloads folder, I made a replacement folder and pinned it in files on the left pane so it is as it should be asshown in this screenshot:

[image]

However the folder is not styled with the icon as before, pretty minor issue but is there a way to get this back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"` to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

(Note `DOWNLOAD` is not plural, it's the only one that isn't...)

Then run `xdg-user-dirs-update`, and the folder should have the correct icon.

Comment: Ah, probably should have tried the singular word too! It is fixed after making that change and running `xdg-user-dirs-update` then
`killall -q -HUP pantheon-files-daemon pantheon-files`

Answer (score 0):

You can try by running

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
killall -q -HUP pantheon-files-daemon pantheon-files
```

in a terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to do. But it doesn't change anything from what I can see.

Comment: What's the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Comment: So I added the line: "XDG_DOWNLOADS_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"", even after running the previous commands and a reboot the situation is still the same, any ideas?